# How to configure a global git hook in GitLab version 11.11?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, gitlab-ce

I'm really confused about how to configure a GitLab global hook. The documentation is clear about [how to set a global hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/11.11/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html#set-a-global-git-hook-for-all-repositories). So I login in my GitLab instance, go to the directory `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks`, and it has 3 files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131 Jun 10 16:22 post-receive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131 Jun 10 16:22 pre-receive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131 Jun 10 16:22 update
```

All the files have the same content:

```
# cat pre-receive
#!/bin/sh
echo "The gitlab-shell hooks have been migrated to Gitaly, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/issues/1226"
exit 1
```

Since they all have a `exit 1`, clearly these hooks aren't being executed anymore.

The [linked issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/issues/1226), is really confusing. It is a roadmap to implement something called [Gitaly](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/gitaly/) but I really don't see how to use it to implement global Git hooks.

Does anyone can show me the step by steps configuration of a git global hook in GitLab CE edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching hooks inside `gitlab-shell` & Since they are moving many things from `gitlab-shell` to `gitaly-ruby`. So that means hooks are working somewhere from gitaly.

Now try this:

```
ls /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/git-hooks
```

Hope you wont find any `exit nonzero` there. Rest is your art.

Comment: Could you give some more information about how to install a hook? Can you just add an additional script or you have to add my script to the already existing files? This is so confusing an undocumented. Thank you in advance, though.