# How to configure global hook in Gitlab omnibus 12.0.3?

Tags: gitlab, hook, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.0/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html) and created a hook in the directory : `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks`, but it didn't work.

Then as explain to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639251/how-to-configure-a-global-git-hook-in-gitlab-version-11-11) I tried to copy the hook to this directory : `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/git-hooks`, it didn't work neither.

Finally I tried this one : `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/gitlab-shell/hooks` but same result.

Does anyone know where should I create it and if there is log to troubleshoot ?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation you linked to in the first sentence would have worked if you had followed it :) The documentation says to create a `custom_hooks` directory in a given repository's directory. None of the paths you mention are indicated in the docs.

Comment: @DrewBlessing I think you read the first part of the documentation for one repository. Here it's for all repositories.

Comment: You're right. In that case, `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks` should have worked. I'm not sure why you had trouble, as long as you created the `pre-receive.d`/etc directories in there.

Comment: Yes you're right, it should work, but I don't know why it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to make it work. I had to change the location in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` by uncommenting and editing the line beginning `gitlab_shell['custom_hooks_dir'] = ...`, then running `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`